# How to convert an URL to an Image?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-arrayadapter, android-glide

I am using GridView and fetching all urls with data from server in android now i want to convert these url's in to images.

Comment: This is an interesting and also vague question, while you know how to fetch data from server,you don't know your question's answer!

Comment: do some R&D before asking the question.

Comment: So.. you want to _download_ the images, or end up with an image which has the url readable on it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use them in Glide like this:

```
GlideApp.with(this).load(ENTER_YOUR_URL_HERE).into(imageView);
```

don't forget to implement it first. For more information just follow this [link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)